# Finding the angle between a line and plane exercise

Tags: plane-geometry

The aim is to find the angle between a line and plane and if they intersect then the point where they do that.

given:  $$ \frac{x+1}{2}=\frac{y-3}{4}=\frac{z}{3}, 3x-3y+2z-5=0  $$

What I have found out:

**s**=(2; 4; 3)
**n**=(3; -3; 2) 
$$|s*n|=|3*2+(-3)*4+2*3|=6-12+6=0 $$
$$|s|=\sqrt{29}$$
$$|n|=\sqrt{22}$$

$$ sin=\frac{0}{\sqrt{29}\sqrt{22}} $$

angle is 0 degrees.

**Solution**

The angle between them is 0, this means they are parallel.

So I take the point P that is on the line

$$ P(-1,3,0) $$
and replace it in the plane equation:

$$ 3*(-1)-3*3+2*0-5=-17$$

-17 is not equal to 0

they don't intersect.

Comment: @Nosrati If the line would be perpendicular to the plane, you expect the normal vector of the plane to be parallel to the line, but their dot product is 0...

Comment: When $\cos=0$ the vectors are perpendicular.

Comment: @Nosrati Right, but which two vectors...? A direction vector of the line and a **normal vector** of the plane...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you calculated is not the angle between the line and the plane, but between (a direction vector of) the line and the **normal** (vector) of the plane, which is a vector perpendicular to the plane.

> What I have found out:
>
> **s**=(2; 4; 3)
> **n**=(3; -3; 2)
> $$\mathbf{s}\cdot\mathbf{n}=3*2+(-3)*4+2*3=6-12+6=0 $$

This dot product is zero, so the line is perpendicular to the normal, not to the plane. But that means the line and the plane aren't perpendicular, but parallel!

That leaves two options:

- they do not intersect, so they have *no points* in common;
- the line lies within the plane, so they have *all points* in common.

It is easy to see that $(-1,3,0)$ is a point on the line; does it lie in the plane?